# Error when launching Gulp: TypeError: dest.on is not a function

Tags: gulp

I started creating my own working enviroment for my personal website using gulp.js until I stumbled across an error I can't seem to solve.

Here is my my code: 
(Note that I am pretty sure the error is in my 'sassCompile' task)

```
/**
 * Initialize all gulp plugins
 */
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var autoPrefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sourceMaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

/**
 * Launch browsersync
 */

gulp.task('sync', ['sassCompile', 'pugCompile'], function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
});

/**
 * Compile sass and css files into css so the browser can read them.
 */

 gulp.task('sassCompile', function() {
     gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')
     .pipe(plumber())
     .pipe(sourceMaps.init())
     .pipe(sass({
         errorLogToConsole: true,
         outputStyle: 'compressed'
     }))
     .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
     .pipe(autoPrefixer('last 2 versions', {cascade: true}))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
     .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
 });

 /**
  * Compile pug files into html so the browser can read them.
  */

  gulp.task('pugCompile', function() {
      gulp.src('src/pugfiles/*.pug')
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(pug())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./HTML'))
  });
```

This will result in this error:

```
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Portfolio\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:564:8)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipe2 (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Portfolio\node_modules\gulp-plumber\index.js:72:14)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Portfolio\gulpfile.js:37:7)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Portfolio\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Portfolio\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Portfolio\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Portfolio\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

My directory:
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhA7.png)

If any other info is necessary I'll make sure to give it.

Comment: can you add your directory structure?

Comment: Added it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because **autoprefixer** does not return a stream.

Try using **gulp-autoprefixer** instead:

```
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
```

...and pass it an object for the options:

```
// ...
.pipe(autoprefixer({
  browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
  cascade: true
}))
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer

Comment: Il'l try this tomorrow and see if this works. Thank you for replying :)

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have tried both solutions and some other error handling methods to get the next pipe to run. Sadly, it keeps coming up with the exact same error. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: Looks like this might be an issue with **autoprefixer**. I've updated my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Not sure what a stream is and what the difference is between gulp-autoprefixer and normal autoprefixer but everything works now thanks to you. Thank you so much for helping me out and I'll do a little research into what caused this error to appear.

Comment: Gulp uses Node's streams. **gulp-autoprefixer** will wrap the **autoprefixer** functionality so that will use streams and be compatible with Gulp. These might help: https://florian.ec/articles/gulp-js-streams/ and https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook